# Is it possible to define a scalar valued function $f$ over positive definite matrices, such that $f(X) \le f(Y)$ implies $X \preceq Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, matrix-analysis

As the title suggests, I am wondering whether we can define a function $f$ over the set of positive definite real matrices $f: \mathbb S_{+}^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ has the property: $f(X) \ge f(Y) \implies X \succeq Y$?

Comment: What should $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ be for $X=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}$ and $Y=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}$?

Comment: No such $f$ exists. Since real numbers are totally ordered, if such an $f$ exists, the positive semidefinite partial ordering would become a total ordering too, but we know this is not the case.